# Webpack configuration for AWS Lambda?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda, for which I need to transpile some modern JavaScript to Node 6.10.

Here is my code:

```
export const handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  console.log('Hello, world');
  callback(null, 'OK');
};
```

Here is what I would like to transpile to (roughly speaking):

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  console.log('Hello, world');
  callback(null, 'OK');
};
```

Here is what I am *currently* generating:

```
module.exports =
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";


Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
const handler = exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  console.log('Hello, world');
  callback(null, 'OK');
};

/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

Here is my Webpack configuration:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/out',
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            babelrc: true
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [ nodeExternals() ],
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ 
      mangle: !debug, 
      sourcemap: debug 
    }),
  ],
};
```

Note that I am also using a `.babelrc` to enable `async`/`await` etc:

```
{
  "presets": [ 
    [
      "env", {
        "targets": {
            "node": "6.10"
          }
      }
    ]
  ], 
  "plugins": [ "transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-async-generator-functions" ]
}
```

How do I configure Webpack to make this transformation?

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047110/aws-lambda-webpack-generated-file) did not work for me.

Comment: What's in your `.babelrc`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to get this working.

Here is the Webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'out'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: "index",
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            babelrc: true
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [ nodeExternals() ],
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ 
      mangle: !debug, 
      sourcemap: debug 
    }),
  ],
};
```

Here is my command for making the bundle that is sent to AWS Lambda:

```
zip -j out.zip ./out/index.js
```

Note the `-j` setting. This strips the path from the file inside the zip.

So the output is:

```
+ out.zip
+--+ index.js
```

And not:

```
+ out.zip
+--+ out
   +--+ index.js
```

Comment: What did you modify in your webpack config? perhaps bold it so it's clearer.

Comment: I added `output.library` and fixed my packaging script.

Comment: In your AWS Lambda, what do you have your handler string set to?

Comment: @AzizJaved Handler string is `index.handler`

Comment: I believe this "hello world" example works, but if you use any dependency from `node_modules`  in handler code, it will stop working, since you prevent all `node_modules` from bundling by using `nodeExternals()`. If you want to bundle also dependencies, just remove `nodeExternals()` from webpack config, or add also `node_modules` directory to final zip file.